# tf.data.Dataset.map() for datasets made from multiple slices

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

The `tf.data.Dataset.map()` for a dataset created from a single slice looks like `dataset.map(lambda x: x/2)`. What would it look like if the dataset was created from two slices? See, for example, the following code. The `map()` function in the last line of the code will work for a dataset created from a single slice, but causes an error for my two-slice case.

```
import tensorflow as tf, numpy as np     # tensorflow 2.0
from tensorflow import keras as kr

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_int8, labels_int8)) # features, labels are numpy arrays

model = kr.Sequential()
model.add(kr.layers.InputLayer(6)
model.add(kr.layers.Dense(     8, activation=tf.nn.tanh))
model.add(kr.layers.Dense(     3, activation=tf.nn.tanh))

model.compile(optimizer = kr.optimizers.RMSprop(), loss = kr.losses.MeanSquaredError())

model.fit(dataset.batch(64).map(lambda x: x/9), epochs = 10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the lambda function in a separate function as shown

```
def map_fn(x, y):
  return x / 9, y

model.fit(dataset.batch(64).map(map_fn), epochs = 10)
```